# No carga localhost en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un problema. Estoy usando NodeJS y mi localhost queda cargando sin emitir respuesta. Dirán que falta un "next()", pero por lo que veo no es así.

**app.js**

```js
const express=require('express')
const morgan=require('morgan')
const path=require('path')
const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const app=express()
//Connect to DB


//Routes

const index=require('./routes/index')

//Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

//Middelwares
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.json)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })) 

//Static fields

//Routes
app.use('/', index)

//Server
app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get('port')}`)
})
```

**index.js**

```js
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.end('Hola mundo')
})

module.exports=router;
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "Mongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.19",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}
```

Se me pudieran ayudar se lo agradecería mucho. Es algo que empzó a sucederme de la nada hace días con varios proyectos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está cuando estas haciendo uso de `express.json` no es una variable es una función `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Era eso! estaba trabado hacía días. Error de novato. Mil gracias!

Comment: Perdón. Cómo hago para dar por cerrado el tema?

Comment: @NéstorAmh si te fue de ayuda, sólo das marcar a la flechita como aceptar respuesta y listo.